# Try to Automate the Build Process for C# Solution through user click

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, msbuild, build-automation

I tried to establish a process through a click button where I can do following activities.

Objective

1. Download the latest code from SVN.
2. Build 2 set of Codes to create dlls and exe-
     (a)Web application in Release mode
     (b)Standalone application in debug mode
3. Then Replace some values of keys inside config files.
4. Then Place them to particular location.

Steps followed so far

Created demo.bat file which will build exe and dlls for Standalone as shown below

---

```
REM * ============================Starting Setup for Standalone======================================
SET Folder= C:\Automating\Application\Source\StandaloneApp\

cd %Folder%App1
msbuild /property:Configuration=Debug App1.csproj /t:clean /t:build

cd %Folder%App2
msbuild /property:Configuration=Debug App2.csproj /t:clean /t:build

del /F /S /Q /A %Folder%Setup\*.*

XCOPY %Folder%App1\bin\Debug\*.* %Folder%Setup\*.* /S /Y /F /Q
XCOPY %Folder%App2\bin\Debug\*.* %Folder%Setup\*.* /S /Y /F /Q
```

Created Another bat file demo1.bat to change command prompt to VS2010 cmd prompt

---

```
%comspec% /k ""c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86
%comspec% /k ""C:\Automating\BuildAuto\BuildAutomation\demo.bat""
```

Created one more cmd files to download from svn

---

```
TortoiseProc.exe /command:export /URL:[URL path] /Path:"C:/Automating/Demo"
```

Finally A web application where from user can click button to download as per svnExport.bat and build the downloaded code as per `demo1.bat`.

---

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\AutomatingPOC\BuildAuto\BuildAutomation\demo1.bat");
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            psi.CreateNoWindow = false;
            Process.Start(psi);
}
```

Downloading event is working correctly, but build is not working. I need help on how can I build the code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why reinventing the wheel? Use available tools, such as [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) and [msbuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) (there are plenty other alternatives as well).
I found Eugene  made a really nice introduction [here](http://www.eugeneduvenage.com/2011/11/continuous-integration-basics-part-1/).

People spent man-years developing and polishing build automation tools. If I were you, I would stop right there and had a look around.

Comment: To be fair to the guy, nothing makes you understand or appreciate a tool more than trying to make it yourself :)

Comment: @Oleksii - Thanks for your suggestion. msbuild is written inside demo.bat file. am i missing someting

Comment: I do not get any error message as such. It is simply showing cmd promt with the availability of msbuild utility because of the "%comspec% /k ""c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86
"

Answer (score 0):

if you set psi.UserShellExecute to false, then you will need to specify that the command to execute is actually "cmd.exe" and that the batch file is an argument.  You'll also have to manages the delay between the time that the request is made and the time the build is actually completed.

Comment: I tried to follow what you saying. Below are the code change done for the event. But the build process still not get started due to this

            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\AutomatingPOC\BuildAuto\BuildAutomation\demo1.bat");
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            psi.CreateNoWindow = false;
            psi.Arguments = @"%comspec% /k C:\AutomatingPOC\BuildAuto\BuildAutomation\demo.bat";
            Process.Start(psi);

Comment: No, you missed something.  Understand the difference between the process you want to run and the arguments to that process.  Judging from this code, you don't fully understand why you are constructing or populating the ProcessStartInfo as you are.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx

Comment: @vicage it's likely to be permissions issue. You need to grant special permissions to the user (under which web app runs) to execute code. By default you cannot do that due to security issue. Try starting an empty command line application and see if it works.

Answer (score -1):

automating a task like this can be done easily with Auto Hot Key. also to automatically download you can use the start command and the type of browser of your choice IE Firefox iexplore chrome ~ then you can automate the download. but do note that with some websites page number may change IE.This address has a specified page code:

[Try to Automate the Build Process for C# Solution through user click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423735)

so instead of putting the regular address in the batch or what ever you chose to use you can put in

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/********

allowing it to find the information

or you can use a mouse/key-board recorder to automate the task.

Comment: The info log is not required. that is why i added below line. psi.RedirectStandardOutput = false;

Comment: automating a task like this can be done easily with Auto Hot Key.